# Automatic answer to interactive shell prompt (yes/no)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-prompt, prompt

I run a bash script.
After some minutes execution it prompts me enter 'Y' or 'N' to continue.
Some minutes later it can prompt me again some times.

Is it possible to answer its questions automatically in common if I know the count and sequence of right  answers (e.g. Y, N, N, N)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a here document:

```
bashscript.shl [options] <<-END
Y
Y
Y
N
END
```

Put any kind of answer you want, passwords, etc.  Will NOT work for ssh or sftp.

Answer (score 1):

The [***Expect***](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) tool used in cases like this. It is useful for automating interaction with CLI applications ([Expect on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)).